# Will all device driver software work with Linux?

Tags: drivers

For example, I write my own device driver for a specific device, any kind really, such as maybe a wireless USB mouse or the like ... how do I add it to the Linux kernel?

Will the kernel support drivers? How would this process go about?

Not too familiar with Linux's kernel system...

Answer (score 0):

A driver is nothing more than a loadable ELF object file, similar to a normal library. Once your driver code has been compiled into such a file, you can load it with the same tools as you use for other drivers (`insmod` or `modprobe`). I'd recommend you read Linux [Kernel Programming](http://blog.rlove.org/2010/07/linux-kernel-development-third-edition.html) or [LDD3](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) for much more information about what you actually need to do. You'll find that loading the driver is actually the easy bit :)

Comment: Compared to the fact that I'm going to be writing my own, I'd say yeah.